# View.Ask in action causes the message box to display repeatedly

Tags: acumatica

I have the following code to override the "Email Purchase Order" action on the PO entry screen.

The code compiles and the message is displayed, but after selecting Yes Or No the message is displayed again and again until I click the X.  Any idea what would cause that?

```
public delegate IEnumerable NotificationDelegate(PXAdapter adapter, String notificationCD);

[PXOverride]
public IEnumerable Notification(PXAdapter adapter, String notificationCD, NotificationDelegate baseMethod)
  {
    if(Base.Document.Ask("Are you sure you want to Email the PO?", MessageButtons.YesNo)
           != WebDialogResult.Yes) return adapter.Get();
          
    return baseMethod(adapter, notificationCD);
    
    
  }
```

UPDATE:

Here's my latest attempt, that's still not working.  The code compiles, but I never get the message box.  Added a trace message to confirm it's hitting the code:

```
public PXAction<POOrder> notification;

[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Notifications", Visible = false)]
[PXButton(ImageKey = PX.Web.UI.Sprite.Main.DataEntryF)]
protected virtual IEnumerable Notification(PXAdapter adapter,
    [PXString] string notificationCD)
{
    PXTrace.WriteInformation("Reached Notification Action - Notification CD = " + notificationCD + '|');
  
    if (notificationCD == "PURCHASE ORDER")
    {
      PXTrace.WriteInformation("Notification Action - If reached");
      
         if(Base.Document.Ask("Are you sure you want to Email the PO?", MessageButtons.YesNo)
   != WebDialogResult.Yes) return adapter.Get();  
    }


      return Base.notification.Press(adapter);
    
}
```

[image: Trace Results]

Answer (score 0):

This happens if the message dialog request is in a place where the framework cant handle a message box.

Try overriding the action itself (21R1):

```
    public PXAction<POOrder> emailPurchaseOrder;
    [PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Email Purchase Order", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
    public virtual IEnumerable EmailPurchaseOrder(
        PXAdapter adapter, 
        [PXString] 
        string notificationCD = null)
    {
             if(Base.Document.Ask("Are you sure you want to Email the PO?", MessageButtons.YesNo)
       != WebDialogResult.Yes) return adapter.Get();  
         return Base.emailPurchaseOrder.Press(adapter);
    }
```

Or for 20R2

```
    public PXAction<POOrder> notification;

    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Notifications", Visible = false)]
    [PXButton(ImageKey = PX.Web.UI.Sprite.Main.DataEntryF)]
    protected virtual IEnumerable Notification(PXAdapter adapter,
        [PXString] string notificationCD)
    {
        if (notificationCD == "EM")
        {
             if(Base.Document.Ask("Are you sure you want to Email the PO?", MessageButtons.YesNo)
       != WebDialogResult.Yes) return adapter.Get();  
        }

          return Base.emailPurchaseOrder.Press(adapter);
        
    }
```

Comment: Hi Kyle, thanks for the reply.  I attempted to override the Notification action first, but I received errors because the base method was protected.  I did not see an action called emailPurchaseOrder in the code for the form, I'll give your code a try.  Thanks again

Comment: I got the following compile error with the code.  'POOrderEntry' does not contain a definition for 'emailPurchaseOrder' and no accessible extension method 'emailPurchaseOrder' accepting a first argument of type 'POOrderEntry' could be found

Comment: What version of Acumatica is this?

Comment: Build 20.216.0024

Comment: Got it, I sent my code snippet for 2021R1, I added 20 r2 in the original post

Comment: Did this work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately it did not, see my update to the original post.  The message box never displays.  You can see the code is reached by the trace messages I added.  I'm confused why it's not working.  Thanks again for all your help on this.